# How to search youtube video in Android by specific keyword

Tags: android, search, video, youtube

I'm trying to search youtube video based on given keyword. So that I can list all found video to display in a list with video thumbnail. I don't find a way to do so. After searching I found this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#examples.

Can I use save for my android application? Or how do I search in Android application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Youtube API code samples in your app on the following conditions:
1. Your app is a free app. 
2. If your app is monetized (paid, ads, and/or in app purchases) then your app has to contain more content and features than just a feature searching Youtube.

Full details here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/creating_monetizable_applications

That being said, you can fully use code samples from Youtube API.  I have done so myself to create an Android app to help people find all my favorite cat videos (shameless promotion): [Cat Roulette](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joshbgold.catroulette)

Anyhow, here is a specific Java code example for searching Youtube videos:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License
 * is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express
 * or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.ResourceId;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Thumbnail;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Print a list of videos matching a search term.
 *
 * @author Jeremy Walker
 */
public class Search {

    /**
     * Define a global variable that identifies the name of a file that
     * contains the developer's API key.
     */
    private static final String PROPERTIES_FILENAME = "youtube.properties";

    private static final long NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED = 25;

    /**
     * Define a global instance of a Youtube object, which will be used
     * to make YouTube Data API requests.
     */
    private static YouTube youtube;

    /**
     * Initialize a YouTube object to search for videos on YouTube. Then
     * display the name and thumbnail image of each video in the result set.
     *
     * @param args command line args.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Read the developer key from the properties file.
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            InputStream in = Search.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
            properties.load(in);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an error reading " + PROPERTIES_FILENAME + ": " + e.getCause()
                    + " : " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests. The last
            // argument is required, but since we don't need anything
            // initialized when the HttpRequest is initialized, we override
            // the interface and provide a no-op function.
            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
            }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();

            // Prompt the user to enter a query term.
            String queryTerm = getInputQuery();

            // Define the API request for retrieving search results.
            YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

            // Set your developer key from the Google Developers Console for
            // non-authenticated requests. See:
            // https://console.developers.google.com/
            String apiKey = properties.getProperty("youtube.apikey");
            search.setKey(apiKey);
            search.setQ(queryTerm);

            // Restrict the search results to only include videos. See:
            // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type
            search.setType("video");

            // To increase efficiency, only retrieve the fields that the
            // application uses.
            search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
            search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

            // Call the API and print results.
            SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
            List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
            if (searchResultList != null) {
                prettyPrint(searchResultList.iterator(), queryTerm);
            }
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Prompt the user to enter a query term and return the user-specified term.
     */
    private static String getInputQuery() throws IOException {

        String inputQuery = "";

        System.out.print("Please enter a search term: ");
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputQuery = bReader.readLine();

        if (inputQuery.length() < 1) {
            // Use the string "YouTube Developers Live" as a default.
            inputQuery = "YouTube Developers Live";
        }
        return inputQuery;
    }

    /*
     * Prints out all results in the Iterator. For each result, print the
     * title, video ID, and thumbnail.
     *
     * @param iteratorSearchResults Iterator of SearchResults to print
     *
     * @param query Search query (String)
     */
    private static void prettyPrint(Iterator<SearchResult> iteratorSearchResults, String query) {

        System.out.println("\n=============================================================");
        System.out.println(
                "   First " + NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED + " videos for search on \"" + query + "\".");
        System.out.println("=============================================================\n");

        if (!iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(" There aren't any results for your query.");
        }

        while (iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {

            SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
            ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();

            // Confirm that the result represents a video. Otherwise, the
            // item will not contain a video ID.
            if (rId.getKind().equals("youtube#video")) {
                Thumbnail thumbnail = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault();

                System.out.println(" Video Id" + rId.getVideoId());
                System.out.println(" Title: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
                System.out.println(" Thumbnail: " + thumbnail.getUrl());
                System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FYI you have to also obtain a Youtube API key as explained here: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found this code earlier. But it didn't mention anything about Android. So I guessed it could be something for JSE only. I don't have the developing machine with me. I will give a try tomorrow. As you have done an app already. I believe it will definitely work for me. In case any issue arise, I will bother you again ;)

Comment: FYI the code sample I provided is of course Java (not Javascript).  Java is the preferred and most-used language for Android development.